# How to include multiple groupings with accumulators in a Morphia query?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, morphia

I'm trying to query a collection in my DB and aggregate them by their date fields. For that purpose, I wrote this query which gets accumulates the field in an array and groups them by their date -

```
db.myclass.aggregate([ { $group : { _id : {$dayOfYear : "$df"}, ts: { $push: {t:"$c"} } } } ])
```

This query when translated to Morphia works perfectly well -

```
datastore.createAggregation(MyClass.class)
                .match(query)
                .group(  Group.id(Group.grouping("$dayOfYear", "df"))
                      ,Group.grouping("ts", Accumulator.accumulator("$push","c"))
                      ,Group.grouping("date", Group.first("df"))
                      )
                .project(   projection("ts")
                        ,projection("date")
                        ,projection("day", projection("$dayOfMonth","date"))
                        ,expression("month", projection("$month","date"))
                        ,expression("year", projection("$year","date"))
                      )
                .sort(Sort.ascending("_id"))
                .aggregate(MyDate.class, AggregationOptions.builder().batchSize(100).outputMode(OutputMode.CURSOR).build());
```

Now I want to re-write this MongoDB aggregation in Morphia which has two sets of arrays that need to be accumulated -

```
db.findings.aggregate([ { $group : { _id : {$dayOfYear : "$df"}, ts: { $push: {t:"$c"} }, prs: { $push: {pr:"$p"} } } } ])
```

For this, I used the same Morphia query as above but included a second *grouping* `Group.grouping("prs", Accumulator.accumulator("$push","p"))` and then added it to `.project` - `projection("prs")`.

This does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was not with the query; it was with my domain object field type for the array I was trying to retrieve.

I created a `String[]` when I should have created an `Integer[]`. Correcting that fixed the issue.

I really wish Morphia threw suitable errors so that I could have debugged this ages ago.